# Unit Testing Dependency Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing

I have inherited some existing projects where the developer was using `Dependency` properties rather that `INotifyPropertyChanged` for WPF change notification.

I am in a position where I need to retro-fit unit tests to the entire solution.

Some of the dependency properties in the `ViewModel` get directly updated asynchronously from some background worker process, so I need to hook into these updates via my unit tests. (I cannot changed the code and use callbacks).

How can this be achieved ?

A lot of developers seem to favor dependency properties over `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but they seem very difficult (if not impossible) to write unit tests for.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Could you list which aspects you wish to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`DependencyPropertyDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.aspx) to attach a changed handler to a dependency property:

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TextBox.TextProperty, typeof(TextBox)).AddValueChanged(textBox, OnTextChanged);
```

However, there are a [slew of reasons](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/03/view-models-pocos-versus.html) not to use dependency properties in your view models. Given that you've inherited the code, I would suggest writing unit tests to assert the behavior of the code and then switching over to use `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: +1 for not using Dependency Properties in your ViewModels - you'll find Dependency Properties are best left to the View.

Answer (score 1):

Since dependency properties can controlled in xaml, there may not be a good way to comprehensively unit test them without launching any windows that are using them.  At which point you're really not unit testing anymore.

That said, you can go after the dependency property by calling the [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx)'s GetValue() and SetValue() methods.

Comment: Oh, and I agree that dependency properties often seem to be more trouble than they're worth.  I'm personally a big fan of keeping the application's view layer as thin as possible, not least of all for the sake of unit testing.  Michael Feathers makes the case well in his essay "The Humble Dialog Box": http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/TheHumbleDialogBox.pdf

Comment: You **can** "hook" dependency properties in code to call your code, therefore you can test them!